# How to hide/mask heroku router logs

Tags: node.js, go, heroku, salesforce

When invoking http requests to external servers like salesforce, we need to send http requests by passing sessionid and userid as a query string in url. But sessionid is sensitive information, we dont want to log it in heroku[router] logs.

Is there any way to avoid heroku router logs?

Thanks

Comment: If you could hide it: are you sure those who have access to the logs don't have access to the running dyno or the session ID? Because if they do, then there's no point hiding it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know enough about heroku to give generic answer but I can help with SF- specific part.

And the answer is ”you don't?" Which Salesforce authentication mechanism and API you're using? Never heard about session id in the URL, it's supposed to go to Authorization header. And when logging in - passing username and password is just one of options, provided when all else fails.
Can you work with other OAuth2 flows, where human consents and logs in directly to SF, heroku doesn't see the password, just redirect with session id or error?
Or there's another flow where you pass username and sign request with certificate. That certificate would have to be manually loaded to SF first and sysadmin would need to allow this user to use this method (make connected app, upload cert, click option about admin preauthorized users and add the integration user's profile / dedicated permission set).
Plus there are things in SF like clamping the session id to IP from which it originated. Could be bad idea if you have 1 Dyno that logs in and N dynos that do actual work - but well, it's make reusing the session very hard.